# Start_times and End_times got switched how do i write a code to flip them

Tags: r, time

In my dataset all_trips I have two columns start_time and end_time. But when filtering it I noticed that some of the start_times were later in the day then there corresponding end_time. How do I write a code to tell r to switch which column the data is in to the other if start_time is later in the day then end_time. Or do i have to manually edit each row like that.

I have no idea how to go about writing this code and when googling I had no luck so I think I might have to manually do every single one but would like to avoid it if I don't have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# find rows where start_time > end_time
idx <- which(all_trips$start_time > all_trips$end_time)
# perform the swaps
tmp <- all_trips[ idx, 'start_time']
all_trips[ idx, 'start_time' ] <- all_trips[ idx, 'end_time' ]
all_trips[ idx, 'end_time' ] <- tmp
```

Comment: Thank you!!! That worked great and I understand how you did it too.